# updating some column values in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a table in which there are 14 columns. Now I have a object corresponds to the table in which I have only 5 values to be updated.
I am using saveOrUpdate method to either save/update the row. The issue is that when I use this method to update those 5 columns, all other 9 column values are set to null.
One solution is that I write update sql query to do the same but I want to use Hibernate API's not sql queries.
Is there any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Foo objectToUpdate = (Foo) session.get(Foo.class, idOfObjectToUpdate);
objectToUpdate.setField1(newValue1);
objectToUpdate.setField2(newValue2);
```

No need to call `saveOrUpdate()` or `merge()`: the object is attached, so everything is flushed and committed at the end of the transaction.

Comment: but isn't it a performance hit as first a select statement is fired and then update one..i don't want to load the object and then try to update it..i want to update the object without loading it first

Comment: It is a tiny performance hit, but that's what you pay for the additional advantage of being able to program with entities, have automatic dirty detection, optimistic locking, etc. If you want to use update queries, nothing forbids you to use them, but it's more complex, less safe, it bypasses optimistic locking and the session cache. Do it in a simple way, and optimize only if necessary.

Comment: actually in my project we have many associations between tables and some of them are lazily loaded..so using select first will be a performance hit and also don't want to use the SQL queries either..so please let me know if there is a way by which I can achieve the above functionality without using sql query or loading the object first and then updating it?

Comment: The fact that the associations are lazy-loaded are a good thing: the performance impact will be reduced. Hibernate has update queries: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#batch-direct

Comment: I think you are digressing and I suppose that you don't have the exact answer to my question

Comment: Have you foolowed the link? It explains the exact syntax to issue an update query in HQL.

Comment: FYI..I have already informed that i don't want to use any query either SQL or HQL..

Comment: It's the first time you mention you don't want HQL queries. Without them, and without using what I suggest in my answer, there's no way to do what you want. It's as simple as that.

Comment: @anand you cannot update an object without actually loading it first. Even if you don't actually call the get/load method, hibernate will have to load the object first in order to make any changes to it. Also your comments are getting a little bit out of hand towards someone with 100k reputation

Comment: I didn't mean to be rude..i apologize for that

Answer (score 0):

Use DynamicUpdate on Entity

Example:

```
Query q = session.createQuery("from StockTransaction where tranId = :tranId ");
q.setParameter("tranId", 11);
StockTransaction stockTran = (StockTransaction)q.list().get(0);

stockTran.setVolume(4000000L);
session.update(stockTran);
```

SQL will be like;

```
Hibernate:
    update
        mkyong.stock_transaction
    set
        VOLUME=?
    where
        TRAN_ID=?
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Hibernate 5 try below code....

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaUpdate<Vehicle> criteria = builder.createCriteriaUpdate(Vehicle.class);
Root<Vehicle> root = criteria.from(Vehicle.class);
criteria.set(root.get("ownername"), "Ashok Parmar");
criteria.where(builder.equal(root.get("vehicleId"), "123"));
session.createQuery(criteria).executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add @DynamicUpdate annotation on your entity class

```
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
public class Product implements Serializable {

//rest of the codes are omitted for brevity

}
```

then update specific column (or columns) value of the table

```
Product newProduct = session.get(Product.class, id);//here id is the product_id for which you are gonna update
newProduct.setName("Pencil 2B");//new name
session.update(newProduct);
```

@DynamicUpdate will update only the modified column(s), rest of the columns won't be affected.